# Sapui5 Add Page into IconTabFilter content

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add Page into IconTabFilter and i've got, but only the title is projected on the screen.

IconTab view :

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({title: "IconTab",showHeader: false});
    var oIconTab = new sap.m.IconTabBar ("idTabBar",{});
    var itemBar1 = new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
        key:"tab1",
        icon:"sap-icon://database",
        content:[ new sap.ui.view({id:"idTabIcon",viewName:"prova5.tabIcon1", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS})
        ]
    })
    oIconTab.addItem(itemBar3);

    oPage.addContent(oIconTab);

    return oPage;

}
```

content of IconTabFilter view:

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    var oPage =  new sap.m.Page({
        title: "Icon Tab Page 1",
        showNavButton: true,
        navButtonPress: oController.navButtonMethod
    });
    var obutton = new sap.m.Button({text: "hello"});
    oPage.addContent(obutton);


    return oPage; 

}
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears when using `sap.m.Page` in your view as a return value in the `createContent` function. If the usage of `sap.m.Page` in your view is not necessary for your purpose try to return another control (e.g. `sap.m.FlexBox`). That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Inspect Elements  and find out div  and in the 
     class "**.sapMITBContent**"  add height in Pixel around 500px and you will get page visible.

Comment: how can I get acces to .sapMITBContent?

Comment: go to developer tools in chrome and go to Elements tab and inspect page present inside iconTabBar you can find class ".sapMITBContent" .

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. It's a "work-around" to check/debug, but not for productive usage.